# How to get data from chart image while preserving order?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I have few images like these,

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

I can extract the names and roles from these images using an ocr tool like tesseract from Python, but I want to preserve the hierarchy along the way.

Please provide some interesting ways to solve this problem. I am not able to think of one proper approach to the problem.

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))) 
import pytesseract# This returns the strings to me.
```

I want information in structured form in any data type, something like,

> For example, in chart 1, Erica is the CEO, and under Erica are Russell, David Work, and so on.

Comment: I'd suggest that you do [Literature review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature_review), i.e. look for "previously published works" on the topic. break the task down. what parts **can** you solve?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I tried few solutions like horizontal and vertical line detection to get contours of boxes from community previously asked questions. But nothing provided a clear way. I was hoping someone here might have worked on similar problem and can provide some insights on where to focus on. I am not understanding how to break the task down.

Comment: the solution, or parts of it, will have to make some assumptions. get the part working that locates boxes. then you only need to pick up everything that's outside of boxes and isn't plain white. that'll be connecting lines. make sure you get one "Connected Component" for each "net" of lines. figure out end points of that net. then figure out which boxes those endpoints are adjacent to. that's the high-level approach I'd go with. you should look into the individual problems. they aren't complicated.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I was able to locate boxes using cv2.Canny and findContours, but I am not able to understand this part "connecting lines. make sure you get one "Connected Component" for each "net" of lines. figure out end points of that net"? I mean I couldn't find any similar problem people might have solved earlier online to go on.

Comment: the boxes are nodes (green). the lines (red) I'd call nets or relations. ignore the top box which is red but should be green, this isn't about finding boxes. relations ("lines") have have more than two ends, hence not really "lines". call them "relations" or "nets" or whatever. each *red* connected component is one net/relation. https://imgur.com/a/opHU9Ta this just required some morphology and binary/boolean operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualization of results:

[image: visualization of results]

Approach:

- box borders and connecting lines ("nets") have certain color/brightness
- work with masks, lists of contours, label maps
- calculate overlap/intersection
- at overlap, check what box and what net participate

Written for the one specific image you provided. The other one is too low-resolution.

For less favorable input data, this would need adapting. That shouldn't be difficult though. Just different thresholds and whatnot.

This should also already work with non-box nodes (e.g. circles/ellipses).

You can figure out the OCR part. This approach and code gives you the individual boxes that you can pass to OCR.

Output:

```
net 1 connects boxes [1, 2]
net 2 connects boxes [2, 3, 4, 5]
net 3 connects boxes [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
net 4 connects boxes [6, 11, 16, 21]
net 5 connects boxes [7, 12, 17, 22]
net 6 connects boxes [8, 13, 18, 23]
net 7 connects boxes [9, 14, 19, 24]
net 8 connects boxes [10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
from math import *
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import pprint
import collections

np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, linewidth=120)

########################################################################

im = cv.imread("9Rsju.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / np.float32(255)

# optional downscale. easier to display.
im = cv.resize(im, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, dsize=None, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

# generally, indices are 0..(N-1) and labels are 1..N and always (index+1) == label

########################################################################
# boxes

# select box borders
boxes_mask = (im <= 0.50) * np.uint8(255)
boxes_mask = cv.dilate(boxes_mask, kernel=None, iterations=1) # cover marginal pixels

(boxes_contours, _) = cv.findContours(
    image=boxes_mask,
    mode=cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    method=cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

numboxes = len(boxes_contours)

# sort contours vertically
def valuation(contour):
    (x,y,w,h) = cv.boundingRect(contour)
    return y + x / 10 # "objective function"

# not vital, just pretty
boxes_contours.sort(key=valuation)

boxes_rects = [ cv.boundingRect(c) for c in boxes_contours ]

def bottom_of_rect(rect):
    (x,y,w,h) = rect
    return (x + w//2, y + h)

def top_of_rect(rect):
    (x,y,w,h) = rect
    return (x + w//2, y)

# boxes mask (fill inside of box)
cv.drawContours(
    boxes_mask,
    boxes_contours,
    contourIdx=-1,
    color=255,
    thickness=cv.FILLED)

# label map for boxes
boxes_labels = np.zeros_like(boxes_mask, dtype=np.uint8)
for (i, contour) in enumerate(boxes_contours):
    box_label = i+1
    cv.drawContours(
        boxes_labels,
        boxes_contours,
        contourIdx=i,
        color=box_label,
        thickness=cv.FILLED)


########################################################################
# connecting lines ("nets")

# select
nets_mask = (im >= 0.7) & (im <= 0.9) # 0.8 + margin
nets_mask = nets_mask * np.uint8(255)
nets_mask &= ~boxes_mask

# create slight overlap
nets_mask = cv.dilate(nets_mask, kernel=None, iterations=1)

# label map
(numnets, nets_labels) = cv.connectedComponents(nets_mask)


########################################################################
# connectivity

overlap = nets_mask & boxes_mask
(y,x) = overlap.nonzero() # pixel coordinates
relations = set(zip(nets_labels[y,x], boxes_labels[y,x]))

by_net = collections.defaultdict(lambda: set())
for (net,box) in relations:
    by_net[net].add(box)

for net_label, boxes in sorted(by_net.items()):
    print(f"net {net_label} connects boxes", sorted(boxes))


########################################################################
# visualization

canvas = cv.cvtColor(im * 0.5, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

for net_label, boxes in sorted(by_net.items()):
    boxes = sorted(boxes)

    headbox_label = boxes.pop(0)
    headbox_center = bottom_of_rect(boxes_rects[headbox_label-1])

    for box_label in boxes:
        box_center = top_of_rect(boxes_rects[box_label-1])

        cv.line(canvas,
            pt1=headbox_center,
            pt2=box_center,
            color=(0,0,255),
            thickness=2)

for (i, contour) in enumerate(boxes_contours):
    (x,y,w,h) = boxes_rects[i]

    cv.rectangle(canvas,
        pt1=(x,y), pt2=(x+w,y+h),
        color=(255,255,255),
        thickness=2)

    cv.putText(canvas,
        text=f"Box {i + 1}",
        org=(x+10, y+40),
        fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        fontScale=1,
        color=(255,255,255),
        thickness=2)


########################################################################
# display

cv.namedWindow("canvas", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow("canvas", canvas)

cv.waitKey(-1)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. All of the boxes have box 25 label, is that expected behaviour?

Comment: from my cleanup/rearrangement of the code, a `box_label = i+1` in that loop was missing. your edit does the same.

Comment: Can you provide how I can crop the image using boxes_rects? Is it possible to crop the original image.

Comment: sure, just disable the `resize` call. then work with whatever bounding box `(x,y,w,h)` you are interested in. slicing goes like `im[y:y+h, x:x+w]`. or keep the `resize` call, and multiply all the coordinates by 2 (resize shrunk the picture by a factor of 2)

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. I can't thank enough.

Comment: I am tweaking iterations and values but I am not able to get it working with this one single hierarchal chart, https://ibb.co/dLnZb1N, Rest are all fine for me, I was able to make it work on rest of my chars. Only this small one causing issues when I try whatever

Comment: several issues there. (1) the box borders have same shade as the connecting lines. (2) the picture bubbles break the box borders. -- instead of coming up with specific ways to handle that specific style, I'd instead recommend training a neural network to predict boxes directly (coordinates), or at least the corners of boxes (response map).

Comment: Training a bounding box predictor seems ideal, I could add wide variety types of chart in training data. I can do some manual labeling . That's really seems like a good idea, I will get on it. But how about lines and connected components. How can I infer which lines connect which bounding box. Can u provide bit of help on how to achieve that output. I'll take this on.