# Region growing from segmentation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Lets say I have segmentation1 (red) and segmentation2 (blue). Both are masks where 1 denotes inside of the region and 0 denotes outside of the region.
I want to select all red regions that are at least partially within the blue region (green).

[image]

What I thought of doing is the following:

```
red_fully_in_blue = red mask * blue mask 
for pixel of red_fully_in_blue:
 if pixelvalue == 1:
  pixelvalue = 2
for pixelvalue of red_fully_in_blue:
 if pixelvalue =2:
  region growing from that pixel inside the segmentation1 (red)
```

This seems a bit convoluted since I'll be doing the region growing algorithm A LOT more than I need. Since I'm working on 3D images, this would make a big time difference.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: can you reformulate the goal? especially the given code makes very little sense to me. what's the green blobs? why are the red and blue things just circles, not filled? what and why are you trying to grow? is the region growing part of the _solution_? please formulate the goal, without implied solution paths

Comment: I think you want to extract **connected components**... the algorithm will label separate blobs. from the intersection mask, you can collect the labels of all overlapped pixels. the set of those labels will denote what red components have any overlap with the blue one.

Comment: working with labels and intersections: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69199832/2602877 and https://forum.opencv.org/t/static-labels-in-watershed/1857/7